# Background Image does not display full image

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I've been trying to fix my background image so that the full image shows its full size. As of now the image display, but it looks like it is zoomed in. I played around with the css and re-sized the image several times but nothing worked. Currently using this template: http://www.tooplate.com/view/2076-zentro

HTML:

```
    <!-- home section -->
    <section id="home" class="parallax-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <h1>Cozinha Bomtempo</h1>
                    <h2>CLEAN &amp; SIMPLE DESIGN</h2>
                    <a href="#gallery" class="smoothScroll btn btn-  default">LEARN MORE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
    #home {
      background: url('../images/telma1.jpg') 50% 0 repeat-y fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: if cover doesn't fit your needs, did you try contain ?

Comment: I just tried that and nothing changed :/

Comment: What are the dimensions of your telma1.jpg? I'm assuming it's similar to the image of the template you're using? http://www.tooplate.com/templates/2076_zentro/images/home-bg.jpg

Comment: The original image is actually 960 x 720, but I already re-sized it to the same dimensions as the home-bg

Comment: Your image is too small, both `contain` and `cover` will scale the image to container. The solution is: use bigger image with lower compression (so you get same size). That way it won't look blured even on best gadgets.

Answer (score 4):

Both cover and contain resize the image to fit the window. To truly be full size, you need

```
background-size: [image width]px [image height]px;
```

To always fit the parent element instead, use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Or size the containing div with the background image to 100% height and width.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to make sure anything about aspect ratio of background, go for background-size:100% 100%;  else go for  background-size:contain